# SQL Join on Multiple Matching Criterias

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Is there a way to join only one time, even though there are multiple rows with the same matching criteria? I am only wanting to join on Name and Region but want Count to be applied to only one of the rows (No specific order).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange request, but you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name, region order by id) = 1
             then t1.count
        end) as count
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.name = t1.name and t2.region = t1.region;
```

However, if you are counting the values in `table2`, then there is a much easier way:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name, region order by id) = 1
             then count(*) over (partition by name, region)
        end) as count
from table2 t2;
```

`Table1` is not needed at all.